# What is this chord called that looks similar to power chords?

Tags: guitar, theory, chords

While watching to some guitar covers I found this chord that looks similar to a power chord. In the cover the guitarist played it on the second and fourth fret. It looks like this:

[image: Chord on fret 2]

[image: Chord on fret 4]

<sub>Images generated with [chordgenerator](http://chordgenerator.net/).</sub>

I want to know how this chord is called. I also want to know how the system behind is working so I am able to write tabs myself with it. It looks like it has a similar system like the power chords with the root note. Where could I place this chord so it sounds good?

Furthermore, is it possible to play this with three notes like a "big powerchord". With big power chord I mean like in this sequence:

```
|-------------------|
|-------------------|
|-------3-------6---|
|---3---3---6---6---|
|---3---1---6---4---|
|---1-------4-------|
```

Comment: As to your three note question, that should work fine because the highest note is just an octave of the lowest so the interval relationships are essentially the same. But the power chords you tabbed are just standard 5 chords. To get them closer to the original chords you mentioned it would be 1-4-3 and 4-7-6 (on E-A-D or A-D-G strings respectively).

Comment: This is still a powerchord. There are many kinds. The common ones are a fifth, but many bands use all manner of powerchords - just listen to Faith No More for a wide variety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interval of a minor sixth. Nameable chords usually need three notes in order to define them. A single interval can be a component of a number of chords. So, for this reason the naming of this chord would depend upon harmonic context; in other words, which other notes, if any, sound with it.

However, the interval of a minor sixth is commonly perceived as the first inversion of a major chord, without a fifth. So, in this case, this would be a first inversion E Major chord without the fifth, having a G# at the bottom, an E above, and no B.

Comment: minor 6th = inverted major 3rd.

Comment: Yes @Tim, that is a *much* more succinct way of putting it!!

Comment: +1 to Bob and Tim. The one place I'm sure it's used, and used as a chord's third below the root, is the intro to "Highway to Hell" by AC/DC.

Comment: I always associate it with *One Vision* by Queen...

Comment: @BobBroadley Thank you for your help! Could you please take a look at my question? I have edited it a little bit to refer to more questions that are connected with this.

Comment: I would also like to add that if this were to be called an E major, that referring to it as first inversion (or E/G#) would somewhat depend on the other instruments.  If the bass is playing an E, then one would not analyze the chord as E/G#, it would just be E major.  However, you could still refer to this shape as it applies to guitar as E/G# but you need to be aware of what the bass player is supposed to do if you are writing up a chart or a formal analysis.

Comment: @Basstickler - an inversion is relevant to the instrument it's played on. That is an E/G#, or 1st inv. Other instruments could be playing all sorts, and the bass could play whatever note - that chord on that guitar is still 1st inv. To get the bass to play it would need to be written specifically for bass, although if I saw that written, I might well play a G# on bass at that point.

Comment: @Tim - That's my point actually.  If you were writing a chart for the whole band, that chord symbol would dictate that the bass play a G#.  Also, if you were analyzing the piece, not specific to guitar, then the bass part would dictate the inversion.  If any of this is exclusively specific to the guitar part, then the symbol E/G# would be perfectly appropriate.  It just depends who the chart is for really.